# How to get from index in PageView onPageChanged in Flutter?

Tags: dart, flutter, pageviews

How do I get the previous index in PageView onPageChanged? Currently, I can get the current index when the page changes with the following code:

```
PageView(
      children: <Widget>[
        SomeView(),
        SomeOtherViews(),
        SomeOtherViews(),
      ],
      controller: _pageViewController,
      onPageChanged: _onPageViewChange,
    );

_onPageViewChange(int page) {   
    print("Current Page: " + page.toString());
  }
```

Does flutter have any built-in function for this? Or should I just manually save the page as reference for the previous page?

- Yes I have thought of that, I just want to know if there's a faster way without having to create a variable

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Decrement page by 1 and store in a class Variable (call setState & modify) or local variable. If current-page is 0 set `previousPage` to totalPageCount - 1.

```
_onPageViewChange(int page) {   
  print("Current Page: " + page.toString());
  int previousPage = page;
  if(page != 0) previousPage--;
  else previousPage = 2;
  print("Previous page: $previousPage");
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use PageView.builder, it will give you page index.

```
PageView.builder(
  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
    // index gives you current page position.
    return _buildPage();
  },
  itemCount: listItemCount, // Can be null
)
```